# linq magic, delete all rec where

Tags: c#, .net

User has list of UserClaims.

I am sending user claimType and claimValue as parameters. Based on that params I want to delete all user claims if any.

User has list of claims and every claim has it's user and type and value.

```
public void RemoveClaim(User user, string type, string value)
{
    var claimsRepository = repository.FindAll().ToList();
}
```

Once again I want to delete all users claims which has type and value sent as params in method.

Comment: Assuming you're using EF: 1. Find all of the claims meeting your criteria  2. loop through the results and delete them.  Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work if "Repository" is a `List`, `IEnumerable` isn't enough, as it doesn't have the Add/Remove functions.

If you meet those criteria, its just `RemoveAll`:

```
repositiory.RemoveAll(c => c.Type == type && c.Value == value);
```

Otherwise, use `Where` with `Remove` (again, needs to support the `Remove` function):

```
foreach (UserClaim c in repositiory.Where(c => c.Type == type && c.Value == value).ToList())
    repository.Remove(c);
```

Comment: Your second snippet will fail due to modifying a collection while enumerating it if there are ever any items to remove.

Comment: @Servy, Added .ToList() so its a different collection

Comment: @gustavodidomenico, Its to avoid the problem Servy pointed out. You need a different collection when removing to avoid an InvalidOperationException

Comment: @gustavodidomenico Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a collection which implements a removal method, such as a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The source collection must work this way, as simply using source.ToList().Remove(...) will only remove from the *copy* generated by .ToList()

Second, you'll need to be wary of removing from a collection while iterating over it, as this will cause an exception to throw and is a very common gotcha when filtering data out of collections. The best way to avoid this is to call .ToList() or .ToArray() against the collection of values to remove, as this will render them into a collection all their own.

```
foreach(var itemToRemove in repository
    .Where(conditionMethod)    // You can lambda here or call a method
    .ToArray())    // Necessary to avoid mentioned exception
{ repository.Remove(itemToRemove); }
```